# Cross Domain upload fails after about 1 minute

Tags: timeout, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, access-control

We have a cross-domain process to upload files using javascript's XMLHttpRequest (which enables a progress events to display a progress bar to users),
this process works fine after setting the needed configurations in web.config:

```
<httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="true">
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

The problem is when trying to upload large files (more than 100 MB), so the request will take a long time (more than 1 minute), the XMLHttpRequest catch a failure event, and the response is as follows (as google chrome display it in the console):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://oursite.net/Controller/UploadFile. Origin http://secondsite.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

But after testing the server side, the file was uploaded and saved, so the Action was completely performed on the server !!

We think that this problem is caused by something such as a timeout (because this problem doesn't occur when the request is not passing a 1 minute).

Note: the server side is an Asp.net MVC project.
Any idea?